# How do I debug a "DependencyProperty.UnserValue" exception in my WPF/MVVM application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a C#/.Net/WPF/MVVM application.

The application runs fine when running through VS 2015.

When I run the application standalone (on a different machine),
I get the following exception at startup:

> An unhandled exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException"
>   occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>
> Additional information "{DependencyProperty.UnserValue} is not a valid
>   value for property "TopLevelItemTemplateKey"

What is really going on?

How do I debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at what is bound to the `TopLevelItemTemplateKey` property. I guess it could be a dependency property registered by you without a default value. In this case just add a default value to the Metadata: `DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(Boolean), typeof(MyStateControl),new PropertyMetadata(false));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you returning directly your value on the get of your Dependency? The good manner would be to test if the variable is null before returning it here an example with an `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourObject> _ocYourObject;
    public ObservableCollection<YourObject> ocYourObject{
        get {
            if (_ocYourObject == null) {
                _ocYourObject = new ObservableCollection<YourObject>();
            }
            return _ocYourObject;
        }
        set {
            if (_ocYourObject!= value) {
                _ocYourObject= value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ocYourObject)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Safe:  It seems odd that this doesn't happen when I'm in the VS Debugger. I've got several Observable collections. I will go through and change them and see if that addresses it.

Comment: This can happen for any object. You should use a logging framework like log4net to log the exceptions and see in which line is your error

Comment: Safe: Totally forgot about log4net. Thx, I will add in log4net.